# Inserting a Qty Value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build out a C# web app that has an input screen. Some of the fields are Qty fields. What could I use as a database type to be able to record a numerical value and how would I write it in my code? Currently using Nchar which records the value but when I try to do some basic adding of Qty1 + Qty2 for example, it doesn't seem to return a value. This is what I currently have:

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Qty1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10);
```

Ive tried numeric and float but they give me something about converting string to int32 errors.

[image]

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: how about save the type to `int`, or `tinyint`. Use `Int32.Parse()` to  get `int` from `string` in c#

Comment: Why on earth would you make a quantity field of type string?

Comment: Goodness... What's the plan when Item8 (9, 10, ...) is required?

Comment: Unless I miss my guess, this schema needs some normalization.

Comment: DB maxim: [Normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works.](http://highscalability.com/mother-all-database-normalization-debates-coding-horror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use int type

```
int qte1 = Convert.ToInt32(yourTextBox1.Text);;
int qte2 = Convert.ToInt32(yourTextBox2.Text);;

int result = qte1 + qte2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to do computations for Qty, then it is not preferred to store it as a character datatype in SQL Server to avoid unnecessary explicit/implicit conversions.

What you can do is:

a) Redesign your table to have Qty as an int datatype.
b) Add validation to your textboxes to accept only numeric values.
c) Convert the textbox value to a numeric type like below and pass this
   to the database Qty field:

```
if (Int32.TryParse(txtQty1.Text)) 
  int Qty1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty1.Text);    
else
  //throw-handle exception
```

d) If you need to store larger numbers or smaller numbers, then use the
   appropriate equivalent datatype BOTH in C# and SQL Server. For e.g.,
   if you need to use `long` instead, then your code would be as below and
   you need to have the Qty field as `bigint`.

```
if (Int64.TryParse(txtQty1.Text)) 
  int Qty1 = Convert.ToInt64(txtQty1.Text);
else
//throw/handle exception
```

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will show you equivalent data types between SQL Server and .NET framework.

---

PS: Please check your table design. You may want to normalize it.
For e.g., you could have a separate table with only ItemId, GroupId, Item, Qty, Cost. And then in the existing table, you can remove all the Item, Qty and Cost columns and keep the master columns. GroupId in the second table would be the primary key of the existing table. This is one way of normalizing it.